# Google News: How to exclude topics like "Pistorius", "Lindsay Lohan", "Casey Anthony", "Charlie Sheen", "Justen Bieber", etc?

Tags: google-news

I use http://news.google.com/.

I would occasionally like to exclude topics from appearing in the "Top Stories" section. Some example topics are "Lindsay Lohan", "Justen Bieber", "World Series", "Superbowl", "Oscar Pistorius".

I know that I can receive Less news from certain news sources such as mtv.com, but can I receive less news about a particular topic?

Under "News for you - Edit personalization", I've set "Entertainment" and "Sports" to never, yet entertainment and sports stories still creep through.

Answer (score 6):

I got tired of waiting for this feature to come to google so I wrote a Chrome Extension that does it for me.  Try it out and see if it fixes it for you.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ekcmgkhakdlcondlgmadpiogjnlggpne

Comment: With your extension topics appear and desappear just after. With my extension topics doesn't appear at all :  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/exclude-topics-from-googl/kkmmbhidlbgoihganelknnokpmcnjffl but you can't use regex expression;

Answer (score 2):

I recently found a very nice way to customize my news the way I want them to be. [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)

The pipe output can be added to Google Reader to filter the results that you want. Here is where I started - [MacWorld - Master your RSS feeds with Pipes](http://www.macworld.com/article/153833/2010/09/pipes.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems Google does not allow the customization of the "Top Stories" feed in any way. Sure you can add your own sections with filters, terms etc, but not Top Stories i don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly same as **excluding** topics but close enough. You can click the three-dot button on an article containing a topic you don't want, then click on "Fewer stories like this" on the menu that pops up. This may help Google learn what topics you don't want to see.

The three-dot menu is hidden when you view the site on a desktop computer. To access the three-dot menu, simply hover over the title and the three-dot menu should appear under the title.

[image: Google News]

Source: https://support.google.com/googlenews/answer/9010862?hl=en&ref_topic=7688382

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Chrome extension for that:

[Exclude Topics from Google News](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/exclude-topics-from-googl/kkmmbhidlbgoihganelknnokpmcnjffl)

Enter a list of keyword (case insensitive) :

```
Lindsay,Lohan,Bieber,Superbowl,Pistorius
```

or

```
terrorist,terrorism,death,violen,war,killed
```

Topics containing one of theses keyword doesn't appears.

You can show hiding topic with a link on top of page.

Mozilla version is here : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/exclude-google-news-topics/

Answer (score -3):

Two ways to remove some particular topics from search result at Google News: http://news.google.com
1. Shortcut: Write in search box like "hollywood -lindsay -lohan"
2. Advance Search page (http://news.google.com/news/advanced_news_search): Write the topic in section: Find results-->without the words

Comment: I don't believe the question is related to a search result. Rather how do you prevent a topic or topics from appearing in the news page.